# What types of RAID does Linux support?

Tags: linux, raid

What types of RAID does Linux support?

Comment: `man md` for starters. There are many more but that's the most common RAID solution in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel supports software RAID levels 0, 1, 10, 4, 5, and 6, plus linear mode (disk concatenation).  It also supports a wide range of hardware RAID cards with varying capabilities.

If you're willing to step outside the kernel, [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) both support the specialized RAID levels of ZFS, and FUSE probably has some other experimental RAID implementations floating around somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.  If you're referring to a hardware RAID then any RAID card with the appropriate Linux drivers will work and any RAID level that the card supports will work with Linux.

If you're referring to a software RAID then you're most likely going to be using `mdadm` which supports 0,1,4,5, and 6 according to https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup.  Of course since it supprots levels 0 and 1 you can combine them to also do 1+0 and 0+1

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [the Kernel Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid) and [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID), at least levels 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1+0 are supported. Since `mdadm` is the tool used to create RAID devices, its documentation is *de facto* the most accurate source of information. From [`man mdadm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html):

```
-l, --level=
      Set RAID level.  When used with --create, options are: linear,
      raid0, 0, stripe, raid1, 1, mirror, raid4, 4, raid5, 5, raid6,
      6, raid10, 10, multipath, mp, faulty, container.  Obviously
      some of these are synonymous.
```

This is pretty much the list already mentioned.